# Scraping - find the name of all sub-class

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find a way to get number of sub-class and their name contained in a root class.
For example, I would like to have in return for the class 'o-container__left u-mt-lg':

- class= "c-site__container"
- class= "c-site__container"
- class= "c-site__container c-site__container__last"

[image]

I'm working with BeautifulSoup. I found this, but it didn't really do what I'm expected:

```
soup.div["class"]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'value'}: and replace value with the class value ! Sorry I’m online through phone

Comment: Please post actual code, not images.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<main class="o-page-content" role="main">
    <section class="o-container">
        <div class="o-container__left u-mt-lg">
            <div class="c-site__container "></div>
            <div class="c-site__container "></div>
            <div class="c-site__container c-site__container__last"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')


for item in soup.findChild('div', attrs={'class': 'o-container__left u-mt-lg'}):
    print(item)
```

> PLEASE NEXT TIME POST THE `HTML` AS TEXT, NOT AN `IMG`